# fake proof of $\forall a. \forall b. a = b \to 1 = 0$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, fake-proofs

I saw a less formal version of this fake proof that claimed to prove $2=1$ but because it assumed $a=b$ from the start I knew why it was wrong. It does seem however that the proof can be used to prove an certain implication I find very odd however. Clearly $\forall a. \forall b. a = b \to 0 = 1$ is false because I could pick $a$ and $b$ to be $1$ and then I would have derived 0 = 1 with no other conditions. So there must be something wrong with this proof that I am not seeing.

proof of $\forall a. \forall b. a = b \to 0 = 1$:

$a = b \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (assume)\\
a+a=a+b  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (x=y \to f(x) = f(y), f(x)=a+x)\\
2a=a+b \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  (a+a=2a)\\
2a-2b=a+b-2b \,\,\, (x=y \to f(x) = f(y), f(x)=x-2b)\\
2(a-b)=a+b-2b \,\, (distributive)\\
2(a-b)=a-b \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (-b=b-2b)\\
2=1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (x=y \to f(x) = f(y), f(x) =x/(a-b))\\
1=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (x=y \to f(x) = f(y), f(x) =x-1)
$

now that I have "proven" $\forall a. \forall b. a = b \to 0 = 1$ I can now pick a and b to be 1.

$
1 = 1 \to 1=0 \,\,\,\,\,\, (a=1, b=1, above)\\
1 = 1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{reflexivity})\\
1=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{modus ponens}) \\
$

So now it seems that I have managed to derive $1=0$. Clearly I messed up given that no one has been able to show $ZFC$ inconsistent and ostensibly this fits well within the most studied aspects of $ZFC$. Either that or a random guy that makes meme's online found the most profound result in mathematics ever.

So where have I missed the mistake?

Comment: And the point of this is?

Comment: Really? I come with a question about where I made a mistake and request help finding that mistake and you are worried about the point of this?

Comment: I am sorry if I am getting this wrong, but you present this problem as a useless speculation that you imply that it is a "fake proof" and it is also not a question for a foundational learning site as SE. This is not a place for "memes."

Comment: @Jake, you never requested help finding the mistake.

Comment: ah. that seems pedantic but ok. I have now edited it to ask my question.

Comment: My apologies if I was saying anything that might have offended you. I am just following by the rules and goals presented by SE.

Comment: It's not really pedantic.  Your first sentence sort of implied that you already knew where the mistake was.  It seemed like you were just modifying the false proof you already saw.

Comment: I know where the mistake is made in their proof. Not mine. I will clarify further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is in the step where you say
$$ 2(a-b)=(a-b) $$
$$ 2=1 $$

Since $a=b$, $a-b=0$, and therefore in that step you are dividing by zero. This proof is about as accurate as saying:
$$ 0=0 $$
$$ (2)(0)=(1)(0) $$
$$ 2=1 $$

Comment: Yup I it was just that simple. So really when doing canceling out divided terms I first need to prove that what I am dividing by is nonzero.

Comment: That is correct